# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacer comparaciones de Booleanos como String en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un pequeño problema, estoy usando JSLT para pasar unas variables del JSP a JavaScript

En este caso son dos booleanos

Se me están creando como `'false'` o `'true'`, me los pasa como string

Al momento de utilizarlos en un función JavaScript tengo un pequeño inconveniente

De la unica forma que me ha funcionado es asi

```
if (b1 == 'false' && b2 == 'true') {
      console.log("Entre al if numero 4");
    }
```

Pero quiero evitar ese uso. Incluso intente usando Boolean pero no me funciono

**¿Hay una forma de pasar ese string a Booleano?**

**¿O quizá puedan indicarme la mejor forma de trabajar esos booleanos?**

```js
var b1 = 'false'
var b2 = 'true';


if (b1 && b2) {
  console.log("Entre al if");
}

if (Boolean(b1) && Boolean(b2)) {
  console.log("Entre al if numero 2");
}

if (b1 == false && b2 == true) {
  console.log("Entre al if numero 3");
}

if (b1 == 'false' && b2 == 'true') {
  console.log("Entre al if numero 4");
}
```

En el JSLT solo hago esto: `<c:set var="hasError" value="false"/>`

y para pasarla al JS hago esto `var hasError = '<c:out value="${hasError}"/>'`

Comment: Tu primera comparación es suficiente, sin embargo yo usaría comparación estricta (`===`), ahora si lo que deseas es una tabla de la verdad usando el Operador `&&` debes usar una estructura `if ... else if ... else ...`. Saludos

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tienes en el JSLT, ¿podrías añadir el código del JSP a la pregunta?

Comment: En el JSLT solo hago esto: `<c:set var="hasError" value="false"/>` y para pasarla al JS hago esto `var hasError = '<c:out value="${hasError}"/>'`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que tal vez desde que tienes a las variables declaradas pudieras hacerles un *cast* a las mismas pasándolos como argumento del objeto [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Boolean).

Así:

```
let b1 = 'false'
let b2 = 'true'

let B1 = Boolean(b1)
```

Si ahora tanto a las variables: `b1` y `B1` les haces un `typeof` verás que obtienes tipos de datos distintos:

```
console.log(typeof b1)
console.log(typeof B1)
```

Lo anterior da como resultado:

```
"string"
"boolean"
```

Si ahora por ejemplo imprimimos directamente el valor asignado a cada una de las variables, notaremos la diferencia:

```
console.log(b1) // "true"
console.log(B1) // true
```

Si ahora usamos ambas variables dentro de un par de condicionales de esta forma:

```
if (b1 === true) {
  console.log(1) //no obtendremos algún valor de salida
}

if (B1 === true) {
  console.log(2) //nos retorna como valor el número 2
}
```

Entonces obtenemos como salida:

- Para el primero no habrá resultado pues los tipos de datos no son lo mismo
- Para el segundo caso obtenemos el número 2 por que la condición se cumple al ser los mismos tipos de datos.

Comment: Creo que me decanto por esto: var b = Boolean('true')

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **JSON.parse()** para convertir strings en objetos de JavaScript

```
let mybool = JSON.parse("true");
if(mybool == true) console.log("verdadero")
```

Otra manera es hacer el uso de **eval()**

```
let mybool = eval("true");
if(mybool == true) console.log("verdadero")
```

**JSON.parse()** Se usa comúnmente
para leer los archivos json, pero puedes utilizarlo asi. y 
**eval()** Se usa para convertir strings en codigo ._. , supongo que eval es la mejor manera

Comment: Es una recomendación de seguridad no usar `eval()`. Saludos

Comment: Solo si va a usar archivos json