# ¿Como usar esta comparación?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de usar unos Booleanos

Al hacer como hago con otros lenguajes: ej Java

```
if(varName){}
```

Pero al hacerlo en Javascript no funciona como quiero

**¿Siempre es necesario hacer if(varName == true)?**

**¿o hay alguna forma de solo hacer if(varName) ?**

```js
var b1 = Boolean('true');
var b2 = Boolean('false');

if (b1 && b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b1) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}


if (b2 == false) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}
```

Comment: Puedes leer [valor *truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) y también [valor *falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy) para que tengas una idea de cómo y en qué casos hacer lo que planteas. Igualmente recuerda siempre usar en lo posible la comparación estricta (`===`). Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al igual que en `java`, la declaracion por `clase`, es diferente de la `declaracion primitiva`.

Siendo `Boolean` y `boolean` objetos diferentes, el primero es generico, el segundo es primitivo, si comparas ambos en `java` sin usar `equals` el resultado deberia ser siempre `false` indistintamente.

Eso mismo pasa en `javascript`, donde no es lo mismo crear un booleano desde la clase, que crear un `booleano primitivo`:

```js
var b1 = Boolean('true');
var b2 = Boolean('false');

if (b1 && b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b1) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}


if (b2 == false) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}
```

Una forma facil de solucionarlo es simplemente **no usar el objeto generico** si no el primitivo, pasando de tener el codigo de arriba a:

```js
var b1 = true;
var b2 = false;

if (b1 && b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b1) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}


if (b2 == false) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}
```

Lo cual **SI**, nos da el resultado esperado en este caso, tambien existe otra forma de obtener el resultado esperado, y es creando tu `boolean` apartir de un `boolean`, en vez de usar un string:

```js
var b1 = Boolean(true);
var b2 = Boolean(false);

if (b1 && b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b1) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}

if (b2) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}


if (b2 == false) {
  console.log("entro al if")
}
```

Asi que vemos una diferencia evidente entre usar un `string` para crear un `Boolean`, y un `boolean` para crear un `boolean`.

Acerca de si es necesario usar la condición:

```
if(varName == true)
```

La respuesta es **definitivamente no**, si `varName` es un `boolean`, entonces esto seria exactamente lo mismo y funcionaria:

```
if(varName)
```

Pero porque usar el constructor `Boolean` da resultados diferentes entonces?

La respuesta es porque el constructor `Boolean` acepta valores primitivos en un rango de `0` a `1`, como puede ser logico... en los cuales `false`  es tratado como `0` y `true` es tratado como `1`, por lo que realmente el constructor `Boolean` puede recibir **2** valores, ya sea un entero entre `0` y `1` o directamente un `boolean` el cual se traduce ya sea a `0` o `1` (`false` o `true`), cuando al constructor `Boolean` le pasas algo distinto de un numero comprendido entre `0` y `1` o directamente un `Boolean`, el constructor pasa a hacer una comprobación `booleana` tal como:

```
if(parametro)
```

Donde cualquier cosa que sea que le pases, si cumple la condicion el valor es determinado como `true`, mientras que si no cumple la condicion el valor es determinado como `false`.

La cosa es que las cadenas de texto al ser pasadas en el constructor son consideradas como `true`, podemos comprobarlo aqui:

```js
if("false"){
  //Como entramos al condicional significa que el string es evaluado como true
  console.log("Hello world!");
}
```

Esto es exactamente el problema, lo que te esta pasando al crear tus `Boolean` es que enrealidad ambos valores son `true` sin que te des cuenta al usar un `string` como valor para crear un `boolean`:

```js
var b1 = Boolean('true');
var b2 = Boolean('false');

console.log(b1, b2);
```

Como ambos son `true` y tu esperas que uno de ellos sea `false`, es por eso el resultado, veamos que ocurre si tenemos la misma condicion con numeros:

```js
var b1 = Boolean(1);
var b2 = Boolean(0);

console.log(b1, b2);
```

Como vemos son evaluados correctamente como `true` o `false`.

Por eso ocurre este extrano comportamiento.

Comment: mi pregunta se basa en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361972/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-mejor-forma-de-hacer-comparaciones-de-booleanos-como-string-en-javas

Comment: Ya hay una respuesta a esta pregunta entonces,  porque volviste a preguntar?

Comment: Supongo que habra que poner como duplicada la pregunta si enrealidad responde exactamente lo mismo que preguntaste en la otra...

Comment: No exactamente es lo mismo, los uso en ambitos diferentes. Me referia que los boolean los recibo como string desde el JSLT

Answer (score 1):

Cualquier string no vacía que intentes traducir a un valor Booleano (ya sea mediante `Boolean(string)` o !!string) te devolverá el valor Booleano `true`, esto es porque cualquier string no vacía es un valor `truthy` independientemente del contenido.

Un pequeño snippet con un ejemplo:

```js
const verdadero = 'true';
const falso = 'false';
const vacio = '';

console.log(!!verdadero, Boolean(verdadero)) // true, true
console.log(!!falso, Boolean(falso)) // true, true
console.log(!!vacio, Boolean(vacio)) // false, false
```

Es lo mismo que decir que el valor Booleano de un `string` será falso siempre y cuando esté vacío.

La opción que yo veo, si como comentas en una respuesta anterior el valor que recibes es un string con 'true' o 'false', es evaluar eso en una función y comparar en base a eso.

Un pequeño ejemplo:

```js
const castStringToBoolean = string => !(string === 'false' || string === '')

const b1 = castStringToBoolean('true');
const b2 = castStringToBoolean('false');

if (b1 && b2) {
  console.log("entro al if cuando b1 y b2 no son false")
}

if (b1) {
  console.log("entro al if cuando b1 no es false")
}

if (b2) {
  console.log("entro al if cuando b2 no es false")
}


if (b2 === false) {
  console.log("entro al if cuando b2 es false")
}
```